# Favicon is blurred

Tags: asp.net, favicon

I want to add favicon to asp.net project.
The icon on the **taskbar** is displayed blurred - no matter what I do.
I work with chrome v35.
**Note** that the favicon is in popup window that is opened from the menu.
This is the code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="rtl">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1' />
    <title>XXX</title>   

    <!-- option 1 -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/App_Themes/.../favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

    <!-- option 2 -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="~/App_Themes/.../favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="~/App_Themes/.../favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="~/App_Themes/.../favicon-48x48.png" sizes="48x48">
</head>
```

What can be the problem?
Thanks,
Yael

Comment: Ensure that your icon is 16x16 and is not losing its color profile if you're resizing from a larger image.

Comment: Note that one .ico file can hold icons of multiple sizes. Maybe you need to add some for the larger sizes.

Comment: helloworld - I checked and it looks fine.
Hans - 32x32 should be enough but I added also 48x48.  
I added a note in my Q.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Chrome.

Info here:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=695487

Comment: You should insert the relevant part of the link you rpovided in your answer in case the link goes dead